# What kind of galvos are used in Moai SLA printers?

Tags: sla

There are some very cheap SLA printers available, working with galvo scanners and 405 nm lasers to expose a fluid resin.

I am looking for the galvos which are used in these projects. Does anyone know a manufacturer or supplier for these components?

One good example is the Moai SLA printer. I've seen the galvos and circuit boards in an assembly video on youtube but I can't figure out where these components are from. See: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UTRUMETt9qY#t=133

The lable says AT40-314X but I can't find anything useful.

Comment: Here you can find some pictures of the components if you don't want to open the youtube link:
https://imgur.com/hdFAnsy
https://imgur.com/lF4b8RT

Comment: After watching the video I don't think that sticker has anything to do with the motors as a very similar sticker is on the control boards.  I think it is a part identifier they use for the instructions.

Comment: They look *quite* similar to these DJ scanners - but I've no experience in galvos, there could be a large difference https://www.ebay.com/itm/20Kpps-Laser-Scanning-Galvo-Galvanometer-Scanner-Set-For-DJ-Laser-Light-Show/223107665479?hash=item33f240ce47:g:rF8AAOSwDyBbeCa6